# Sum already existing rows into one row given specific years

Tags: r

This is my current data

| Year | Economy | GDP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | US | 26 |
| 2000 | China | 24 |
| 2000 | Rest of the World | 100 |
| 2001 | US | 25 |
| 2001 | China | 25 |
| 2001 | Rest of the World | 120 |

I want to add "China" to "Rest of the World" for each year. My final data should look like this. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

| Year | Economy | GDP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | US | 26 |
| 2000 | Rest of the World | 124 |
| 2001 | US | 25 |
| 2001 | Rest of the World | 145 |

Answer (score 0):

We can do a group by 'Year' and with `case_when` replace the 'Economy' values that are no 'US' to "Rest of the World", then get the `sum` of "GDP"

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Year, Economy = case_when(Economy != "US" ~
            "Rest of the World", TRUE ~ Economy)) %>%
     summarise(GDP = sum(GDP, na.rm = TRUE))
```